# Chrome extension development, several JS files, accessing each others globals, how?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

So let's assume we have **three** js files, **core.js**, **one.js**, **two.js**.

core.js file is a library script file to provide util functions to be used in **one.js** and **two.js**.

**manifest.json** :

```
{
        ...         

    "permissions": [
            "storage",
            "http://*/",
            "https://*/",
            "tabs",
            "management",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
        "background": {
                "page": "background.html"
        },

        "content_scripts": [
                {
                        "all_frames": true,
                        "matches": [
                                "<all_urls>"
                        ],
                        "js": [
                                "core.js"
                                "one.js"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

then it seems not to. I've also tried to add **core.js** before **one.js** above as well:

**core.js** currently looks something like this:

```
(function() {

        var w = window; 

        w.Core = {
                myfunc: function() {
                        console.log(111)
                }
        } 

})()
```

**one.js** currently looks something like this:

```
(function() {

        var w = window; 

        console.log(w.Core.myfunc(); 

})()
```

I am just assuming it will be available on the **global scope**. but maybe not?

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, but i also asked how it can be done without backgound.html by adding core.js and one.js together in content_scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just update the question with how I am using it in one.js

Comment: Yes, seems to work on a fresh extension. not sure why not here. i will keep trying. thanks for the links :)

Comment: Hmm, seems to cause an issue with symlinks when not in background.html but from content_scripts. I have a symlink to a file.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27185

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27185#c46 "Symlinks work for all assets EXCEPT content scripts."

Comment: This is a very useful find. If there's no existing answer on SO, I suggest adding one here.

Comment: Yes, i's horrible. I created a job that copies the original source to the desired symlink position to get around. Not ideal.

Comment: Do you know how a script within the extension folder, can be included on any site dynamically? Meaning, that i add the script to the local script using javascript rather than matches. When I set src it is resolving to http://original.domain.com/path/to/local/script

Comment: See this: https://hastebin.com/cufojupire.js